# libvirt connection as non-root user

Tags: centos, centos7, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, foreman

I'm trying to configure a libvirt compute resource in Foreman and have both KVM and Foreman installed on the same Centos 7 host.

Adding the compute resource with `qemu+ssh://root@hypervisor.example.com/system` works but not `qemu+ssh://hypervisor.example.com/system` which uses the `foreman` account.

Using the `foreman` account, I get the following error:

```
bash-4.2$ virsh -c qemu+ssh://hypervisor.example.com/system list
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: End of file while reading data: : Input/output error
```

I've added `foreman` to the `libvirtd` group and have configured `access_drivers = [ "polkit" ]` in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`.

I followed https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/SSHPolicyKitSetup and created:

- `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/90-foreman.rules`

  ```
  polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
      if (action.id == "org.libvirt.unix.manage" && subject.isInGroup("libvirt")) {
          return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
  });
  ```
- `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-libvirt-remote-access.pkla`

  ```
  [Allow foreman libvirt management permissions]
  Identity=unix-user:foreman
  Action=org.libvirt.unix.manage
  ResultAny=yes
  ResultInactive=yes
  ResultActive=yes
  ```

Neither configuration works, what did I miss?